# Android-what to do with chosen image?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code on my button, which allows me to click a button and choose a PDF file. How do I get the path of the PDF file, and actually do something with the file (because right now I can only click on the file and nothing happens). I want the image to be put in an API do to something to the image.

```
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must override the [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) in order to get what you need.

You will be able to get what you want (the file path) with the resulting intent. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
{
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri fileUri = intent.getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put that? In the .java file for the specific button or what? This is my code so far.                                   
                                                                                 
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

            }
        });

Comment: You can override the onActivityResult in your activity.

Comment: the main activity or that specific activity?

Comment: The activity that is expecting the intent result. In your case, it will be the one that you have your "button2".